# Xamarin.iOS on macincloud development and automatic provisioning setup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mac-in-cloud

I'm trying to develop a cross-platform app using xamarin forms and mac-in-cloud. Specifically with ios, I'm trying to set-up automatic provisioning since I originally got the error when debugging: >Could not find any available provisioning profile for (app name).iOS on iOS

So, after researching into the issue I put my apple developer acct info in, and when trying to use automatic provisioning. I get an error under Team: >There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit. There are no current IOS devices on this team matching the provided device IDs.

Now, following the research rabbit hole, I go to the apple developer portal, try and register device, select macOS, insert Hardware UUID of mac mini into device ID, so on. And no change to error(s).

Question time, am I setting it up completely wrong? Other (older) articles/forums suggest linking an ios device via itunes, however, that seems counterproductive to my objective. Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies for any naiveté.

Comment: Hi, if you select automatic provisioning, you need a paid apple account. If you not owning a Mac, you also could have a try with [Xamarin Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart), and that will need you to install iTunes and a physical device to build and test.

Comment: Hello, yes, I do have a apple developer acct. So, if I'm paying for remote access to a mac then do I also need an IOS device? Or wouldn't the mac be enough to emulate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to develop with the mac? Is it a iOS (iPhone) app? If so you can just use the simulator on the mac, and the mac does not need to be registered.

Try manual provisioning in VS
Signing Identity > Development (your name)
Provisioning profile > probably will be vs (something)

Also in VS go to Preferences > Apple Developer Accounts > make sure your account is listed. Then on the right hand side, click 'View Details' then 'Download all profiles'

Restarting VS or the mac may also help.